# Finding ratio of numbers of records

Tags: sql, elasticsearch, elastic-stack

Assume I have a database table with three columns, `source`, `dest`, and `data`. I want to compare the number of records with different `dest`s for each `source`.  I can get the raw numbers with something like:

```
SELECT source, dest, COUNT(*) FROM table
  GROUP BY source, dest
```

and get a result that looks something like

```
source dest COUNT(*)
A      x    100
A      y    100
B      x     75
B      y     78
C      x    200
C      y      0
```

What I want, though, is a comparison of each `source`'s different `dest`s, maybe via standard deviation: a result that would look like:

```
source SD
A        0
B        1.5
C      100
```

I would even be okay with assuming that there are only two possible `dest` values across the whole table and have it just report the difference between the two:

```
source DIFF
A        0
B        3
C      200
```

Is there any way to do this in SQL? I'm targeting [ElasticSearch SQL](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/xpack-sql.html), but I'd be happy for any input and I can try to translate to that dialect.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want `-`:

```
SELECT source, MAX(cnt) - MIN(cnt)
FROM (SELECT source, dest, COUNT(*) as cnt
      FROM table
      GROUP BY source, dest
     ) t
GROUP BY source;
```

Standard deviation is really not meaningful when you have only two values.

Comment: . . . and for standard deviation I believe just replace `MAX(cnt) - MIN(cnt)` with `STDEV(cnt)`.

Comment: Unfortunately, Elastic doesn't support sub-selects that have a GROUP BY clause. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/sql-limitations.html